# Ionic 3: Passing Data when Setting the root page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am checking some localstorage info and depending on the info I get I want to load the appropriate page.

So in my `app.component.ts` I have the following.

```
export class MyApp {
  rootPage: string;

 constructor(){
  if(dataFound)
   this.rootPage="HomePage"
  else
   this.rootPage="OtherPage"
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can pass data when setting the `this.rootPage`.

Keep in mind that this is the initial load of the app. If this happen after the app has loaded I can do `this.navCtrl.setRoot()` which will allow me to pass parameters along with the page.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

As @gaborp said, but with a little difference :

1. In your root:

   `<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" [rootParams]="rootPageParams"></ion-nav>`

   `this.rootPageParams = {'username': "David" }`
2. In the view you want to read that param (this is the difference):

   `this.username = this.nav['rootParams'].username;`

All I read was about tabs, but nothing for a simple ion-nav, so that is the way I did it.

Comment: While reading back the param in step 2, `this.nav` refers to `NavController` or `NavParams`?

Comment: It refers to NavController

Comment: @rmalviya Thanks for the clarification about NavController it's worked now.

Answer (score 6):

Also you can use NavParams:

this.rootPageParams = {
      id: "123",
      name: "Carl"
    };

```
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" [rootParams]="rootPageParams"></ion-nav>
```

Then access the params from your root page:

let id = navParams.get('id');
let name = navParams.get('name');

Comment: So if I set the root page to "HomePage" will I be able to access the params?

Comment: Yes. In your homepage.component.ts you should import NavParams:
import { NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
then inject it and access parameters:
 constructor(private navParams: NavParams) {
     let id = navParams.get('id');
     let name = navParams.get('name');
  }.
You can set NavParams with ion-nav component, as in the example above, or programmatically, like this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.rootPage,this.rootPageParams)

Answer (score 2):

### IONIC 3:

So, starting from the page where you want to set `OtherPage` as the new root page you can write:

```
let rootPageParams = {'currentClusterID': 2 }
this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(OtherPage, rootPageParams);
```

Then, in `OtherPage`:

```
ngOnInit() {
     let currentClusterID = this.navParams.get('currentClusterID');
     console.log('# OTHER PAGE: currentClusterID', currentClusterID);
}
```

If you want to use html template to set your root instead of typescript you can write:

**.TS:**

```
rootPage: any = OtherPage;
currentClusterID: number = 2;
```

**.HTML:**

```
<ion-nav 
    main #content 
        [root]="rootPage" 
        [rootParams]="{'currentClusterID':currentClusterID}">
</ion-nav>
```

Comment: If I set `[rootPage]="tabsPage"`, then in tabsPage navParams doesn't have params which were set through `rootParams`. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You can place getter and setter function for the MyApp which can be accessed by other component when you import MyApp component in it, by which you can pass data between component

Or you could pass it from parent to child or vice versa using `@input` and `@outputemitter`

Or use an Observable decorator service in order to communicate between services

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) section in Ionic Docs.

You will be able to pass your data (if found) to your `OtherPage` from the `RootPage` by simply going through the same.

You can also have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45417083/how-can-i-pass-data-back-to-my-root-page-in-ionic-2) given  by @sebaferreras for more understanding

Happy Coding!

Comment: In Ionic 5, Events has been deprecated